# Is [map] synonym of [dictionary] really a good idea?

Tags: discussion, tags, tag-synonym-process

I guess (correct me if I'm wrong), [map](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/map) is made a synonym of [dictionary](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/dictionary) because both of them can be used to refer to the language-agnostic abstract data type. However, in the real world, most questions with these tags are language-specific.

Personally, it feels weird to see a C++/Java question tagged with [dictionary](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/dictionary). The feeling gets stronger considering there are many [map](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/map) related tags, e.g, [unordered-map](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/unordered-map), [multimap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/multimap), [treemap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/treemap), [hashmap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/hashmap), ...

If it were a good idea, why stop here? There are also [associative-array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/associative-array), [hash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/hash), [hashtable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/hashtable), [lua-table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/lua-table), ... Yes, these tags are more language-specific, but like I said, [map](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/map) and [dictionary](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/dictionary) also have specific meanings in certain languages.

Comment: even worse, the people that don't know `map` is a language construct and try to use it when referencing something `geomapping` related.

Comment: Other way 'round, actually -- [tag:map] is a synonym of [tag:dictionary]. Order matters. It means that if you try to put in [tag:map], you really get [tag:dictionary]; if you put in [tag:dictionary], you don't get [tag:map]

Comment: To me, "map" is a verb and "dictionary" is a noun, so this seems like a strange synonymization.

Comment: Related on `[main]`: [What is the difference between a Map and a Dictionary?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/2884068/464709)

Comment: @QPaysTaxes Ah, right, of course, updated now.

Comment: Does anyone have the link to the old tag wiki for `map`?

Comment: Even worse, [**`map` is a function**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Map_(higher-order_function)) not a data structure, e.g. in many [tag:haskell] questions such as [this](http://stackoverflow.com/q/29795018/1048572)

Comment: I guess that Maximum A Posteriori (MAP) techniques are off-topic in SO?

Comment: Not sure about other languages, but in Python, queries around map function tagged with the dictionary data structure instead will surely confuse a lot of people.

Comment: @Bergi, and Scheme, Common Lisp, Emacs Lisp, Standard ML, OCaml, Idris, Agda, Coq, Scalaz, Python, Perl, Ruby, and probably more.

Comment: @JonEricson 'map' is both a noun and a verb. At least in my experience, the noun form is more common.

Comment: @kolossus Downvoter and nonprogrammer here. The comments and answers are pretty convincing that these are not synonyms. However, I am not sympathetic to the OP, who seems to want to misuse [tag:map] in the sense of a dictionary (as can be done now) and have it display as [tag:map] instead of [tag:dictionary]. That UI extension would do more harm than good; and, besides, programmers should know what "dictionary" means in the context of computer science.

Answer (score 66):

I think synonymizing [dictionary](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/dictionary) and [map](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/map) is definitely a bad idea. In particular, **map** actually means something *completely different* in functional programming. See Lisp. Or even Python, for that matter, which has both `map` and `dict`.

Comment: not to mention `map` as a function.

Comment: @DanielA.White: "map means something different in function programming" means "map as a function".

Comment: Even in Python, even in Python...

Comment: If you want to break the synonym, you should also propose a good way to keep the concepts "mapping function", "map datastructure" and "geographic maps" properly disambiguated.

Comment: @Deduplicator this is already addressed in tepples' answer, which I think is the way to go.

Comment: @Will Well, this answer leaves it hanging. And anyway, tepples would also need some synonym containing map mapped to dictionary, perhaps [map-datastructure]. And the only kind of DO_NOT_USE disambiguator which might perhaps work is a blacklisted tag.

Comment: @Deduplicator so maybe it *should* get blacklisted. "map" is no good a tag precisely because it's two concepts: one is dictionary, the other is function. Whether we need just [dictionary] or [map-datastructure] as well, is yet another separate question. In Haskell e.g. there *is* a Map data-structure, and there is a hash table too. Both conceptually a dictionary... But perhaps, for Map the [dictionary] tag alone is enough, and for hashtable *two* tags, [dictionary] and [hashtable] would be appropriate, so maybe there's no need for another tag like [map-data-structure] there, after all.

Answer (score 4):

The real problem is that [map](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/map) conjoins two different matters, and while for one of them (data-structures related) the synonymization is perfectly fine, for the other (function-related) it makes no sense whatsoever. This is all language-agnostic still.

The true solution is for [map](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/map) to be split into [map-data-structure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/map-data-structure) and [map-function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/map-function) (that I've created today, incidentally), and *only then* for [map-data-structure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/map-data-structure) to be merged into [dictionary](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/dictionary).

Simply merging [map](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/map) into [dictionary](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/dictionary) (with the synonymization hack to boot) is insane (/strong language). It also breaks the tag edit interface, as can be seen in [my recent question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/297328/849891).

Comment: Well, two major uses (which are the ones which really count, the function and the datastructure), but also a minor use (spatial maps). The problem is probably that they are all one-and-the-same, seen from the right angle. Anyway, if that (or something like it) is ever done, we need a blacklisting of plain [map] for sure.

Comment: @Deduplicator what is spatial map? do you mean a representation of actual geographic maps?

Comment: @Deduplicator if you need it, you can always create the [spatial-map] tag... :)

Comment: Yes, a map of some location (which need not be flat), but also of any arbitrary object, for whatever properties may be desired. If I ever need it, I might.

Answer (score 3):

Based on the (mis)use I see, I'd prefer to desynonymize [map](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/map) and turn it into a DO NOT USE disambiguator, with an excerpt directing the asker to instead use one of these:

- [dictionary](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/dictionary) for things like Java `java.util.Map` or C++ `std::map`
- The recently created [map-function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/map-function) for `map` in functional programming, such as PHP `array_map` or C++ `std::transform`
- [maps](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/maps) for geography
- [mindmapping](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/mindmapping) for whatever that is

Comment: `mapreduce`? then what about people who want to do `mapfilter`? or `mapmap` or `mapreducemapfilter`?

Comment: `mapreduce` doesn't make sense for the function `map`. (It's also confusing with the Google technology!) Perhaps `map-function` or something would make sense.

Comment: or `map-higher_order_function` to be completely pedantic and clear, like the folks over at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Map_(higher-order_function)

Comment: @TikhonJelvis  coincidentally, I've created [tag:map-function]  today, after http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/297328/849891.

Answer (score 0):

A lot of tags have a specific meaning in some language or another, but more often refer to a generic concept and that's what the tag wiki covers. The map and dictionary constructs are pretty similar when language-agnostic. Many tags should be fairly broad, so we can combine them with other tags to isolate a particular concept.

When you mean the language's implementation of the concept, tagging with [language-construct](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/language-construct) or ([language](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/language) and [construct](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/construct)) seems more appropriate than co-opting a tag that would otherwise be very broad.

We don't use [map](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/map) to refer C++'s specific map implementation, even though it has some oddities you might care about. There aren't any real differences between a conceptual [dictionary](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/dictionary) and [map](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/map) that I know of.

The specific tags like [hashmap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/hashmap) include useful information about the algorithm being used, especially when the question has anything to do with performance or collisions. Same with [lua-table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/lua-table), and [associative-arrays](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/associative-arrays) can behave somewhat differently in Bash and PHP.

So I don't think this is the best synonym, but I do think it's perfectly valid.

Comment: *We don't use map to refer C++'s specific map implementation* May I ask why not? Since you are talking about C++, note that `std::map` isn't the one with the same data structure as Pyton's `dict`, `std::unordered_map` is. If a question is tagged with **c++** and **dictionary**, which one is OP talking about then?

Comment: If we used [tag:map] for C++'s map, what would we use for Java's map? They have very different interfaces. If we used [tag:dictionary] for Python's dict, what would we use for .Net's dictionary? If the OP cares about a particular implementation, it should show up in their code or they should tag it ([tag:hashmap]).

Comment: **c++ map**, **java map**, **python dicitionary**, **c# dicitionary** is clear enough for me. The language tag provides the context for these tags so that they are not confusing. The fact that C++'s `std::map` and Java's `Map` have different interface isn't a big problem in my opinion. Even **arrays** have different interfaces in different languages.

Comment: @YuHao that's my whole point: [tag:map] should refer to the concept and be combined with a language to specify a particular interface. If you care about the implementation, then [tag:hashmap] and a language covers that. The map and dictionary concepts are the same, so having them be synonyms makes a fair amount of sense.

Comment: _There aren't any real differences between a conceptual dictionary and map that I know of._  Most questioners in my experience are focused on the specifics of the particular languages/problem they have and not on the conceptual similarity in language-agnostic way. A map is the same as a dictionary might be obvious to an experienced programmer, but many newbies could be stumped if they had a question around language specific `map` which gets converted into dictionary question instead,