# Tags clash because of a tag synonym

Tags: support, bug, tags, tag-synonym-process

*edit:* this question is different and [not a duplicate of this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/296485/is-map-synonym-of-dictionary-really-a-good-idea), because I'm talking about language-agnostic distinction between data structure and function, in general. Which is of course self-evident, that such a distinction exists.

---

Trying to edit tags on [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/29594516/849891), I couldn't.

[image]

This tag is imprecise; the question is talking about the `map` *function*. Editing, the "map" tag indeed appears as a distinct - and correct - possibility, but after the edit, [dictionary](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/dictionary) appears instead on the question.

[image]

Looks like an incorrect tag-synonym request was approved at some point in time.

The original "map" tag should probably have been split into the data-structure related stuff (which *can* go into the [dictionary](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/dictionary)), and a new function-related tag, "map-function" (there exist [fold](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/fold) and [filter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/filter) after all). In fact I went ahead and created [map-function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/map-function). From a cursory [search](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bdictionary%5D+map+function) it looks like there's a lot of such questions on the site. In fact, I've just edited [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30148827/849891), for starters.

The system should have prevented the creation of a duplicate tag synonym in the first place.

Comment: "The system" for that is the users. I'm not sure if you mean something else by your last sentence. By the way: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/search?q=dictionary+map

Comment: You should make your case for the map-function being more important than the map-datastructure on those other questions Frank linked, specifically http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/296485/is-map-synonym-of-dictionary-really-a-good-idea. I wouldn't hold my breath. Anyway, could you elaborate why [mapping] is unsatisfactory?

Comment: @Frank the duplicate synonym for an existing - different - tag shadowing its use, is a clear break in the site's functionality, and should be automatically prevented, it seems; unless the two tags are really equivalent, which in this case, they clearly are not. Was not aware of the discussion, will read, but IMO to do this was wrong, with these specific tags.

Comment: @Deduplicator not *more* important; *equally* important. as in, two separate existing phenomena. ah, you meant on questions; well, I only edited a few where it was clear as day that they talked about function; one talked about both structure and function, so I used *both* tags on that one!

Comment: I mean that the only way the "system" knows that they are essentially different is through the votes of users. Users voted them synonyms (arguably wrongly) and there is no systematic way to override the community's votes when they are wrong, unless you have something to propose...? The second thing you bring up is that synonyms work by overwriting with the synonymized tag... if that's your beef, maybe you should try a feature request...?

Comment: @Frank I present evidence, and am happy with the community taking over from here. Right now the tag functionality seems broken - two different tags are shown, but act as if there were only one (in my 2nd image).

Comment: If you're arguing for "the second thing" (from my last comment), I think you'll have more success framing it as a feature request. If you call it a bug, it will be closed as status-bydesign (since it is designed how the SO developers intended, and hence not technically a bug).

Comment: It seems to me, use of an existing tag as a synonym to another is clearly wrong and should just be prohibited, no matter the votes; if tag merge is what's desired, then it should be done as such, not as a hack with the synonyms.

Comment: @Frank you absolutely sure it is by design and not an oversight? I'm not.

Comment: Yes, I'm pretty sure. You could reframe this question as "tag synonymy shouldn't exist" and try to get it reopened; or start a new one with that theme. No one else is reading these comments but us :)

Comment: @WillNess 99% of the time, synonyms are defined between two existing tags.  Synonyms are only created where they are needed.  So this is all by design.  The fact that two different "topics" got included in the same tag is just a lack of due diligence on the part of the community.  As was already suggested, you should start a thread on disambiguating the "map function" usage.

Comment: @JasonMArcher you mean post a question about it?  I have an _answer_, that a lot of questions need to be retagged, but what would be the question? I'm not versed in _meta_ ways, you see.

Comment: @JasonMArcher and besides, I really think [this answer](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/296693/849891) is the way to go.