# Unable to edit tags to include [map]

Tags: support, tags

I tried to include [map](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/map) in the list of tags of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32373301/1903116), as it is related to JavaScript Maps. But it won't allow me to do that. I asked my friends from the Python room to try that, they couldn't do either.

Is this a bug or there is a specific reason behind this behaviour?

Comment: Related read [Is \[map\] synonym of \[dictionary\] really a good idea?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/296485/is-map-synonym-of-dictionary-really-a-good-idea). There is another tag [tag:map-function]. (However I am unaware if it fits in this case)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[map](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/map) is a synonym of [dictionary](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/dictionary), and the question already has that tag.